# Parse curl information in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, stripe-payments, plaid

This is my first time using curl in my Rails 4 App.  I am trying to use Plaid with Stripe.  I am able to successful exchange the public token for the stripe bank account token.

[Stripe with Plaid ACH](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid)

Here's my controller action.

```
    def create
      results = `curl https://tartan.plaid.com/exchange_token \
        -d client_id="CLIENT_ID" \
        -d secret="SECRET_KEY" \
        -d public_token="#{params[:public_token]}" \
        -d account_id="#{params[:meta][:account_id]}"`
    end
```

In Terminal with JSON.parse(results)

```
{"account_id"=>"ACCOUNT_ID", "stripe_bank_account_token"=>"12345678abcd", "sandbox"=>true, "access_token"=>"test_citi"}
```

How does one get the stripe_bank_account_token into the controller?

**UPDATE**

I am using the Figaro Gem to hide the params/credentials..

```
results = 
`curl https://tartan.plaid.com/exchange_token \
  -d client_id="#{ ENV['PLAID_CLIENT_ID'] }" \
  -d secret="#{ ENV['PLAID_SECRET_KEY'] }" \
  -d public_token="#{params[:public_token]}" \
  -d account_id="#{params[:meta][:account_id]}"`

   # here's how I get the stripe_bank_account_token
    break_down = JSON.parse(results)
    x =  break_down.select { |key, val| key == "stripe_bank_account_token" }
```

Comment: just use the ruby plaid library. https://github.com/plaid/plaid-ruby you should never ever call the shell from ruby code.

Comment: The shell call is on Plaid's website. I took their directions as if you could use one or the other?  Is this curl from Plaid the security issue? @MatthewArkin

Comment: the issue is that you're executing a shell command from rails that is taking user input. If I modified your front end (which any user can do by right clicking in Chrome), then I can send some malicious input in the params that might execute a different command instead of curl. So I could set public_token to wipe your server, dump all your database passwords, etc.

Comment: Thanks for beating this into my head.  I am trying to use the Plaid Ruby Gem but I am getting this error `You must set Plaid::Client.client_id before using any methods which require authentication! It's current value is...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't pipe to curl from Ruby code especially when it involves user input.

Rather you should use the built in Ruby HTTP Client, a gem like RestClient, or even better the Plaid Ruby Gem.

`gem install plaid`

then just

```
require 'Plaid'
Plaid.config do |p|
  p.client_id = '<<< Plaid provided client ID >>>'
  p.secret = '<<< Plaid provided secret key >>>'
  p.env = :tartan  # or :api for production
end

user = Plaid::User.exchange_token(params[:public_token], params[:meta][:account_id], product: :auth)
user.stripe_bank_account_token
```

Comment: Thank you for the information!  The Plaid Ruby Gem is helpful.  Nevertheless, I reached out to Plaid about piping to cURL.  Here's their response "As long as the requests are not exposed on the client side, meaning that the client Id and secret are not exposed – you should be fine to use a request handler and make calls directly to the API."  My Client ID and Secret Key are not exposed... I am using Figaro and have the ids stored in my application.yml file.

Comment: The issue is not that the client id and secret key is exposed to the client, your issue is that you are passing unsanitized client input to your shell. So as a malicious entity, I can modify the Plaid button to instead of sending you a public token instead send you a piece of text that will escape out of the curl command and instead do something malicious. All that results = `curl https://tartan.plaid.com/exchange_token ` is copy and paste that into your terminal, so if I was to do something like set public_token to "&& rm -rf /" a simple form post to your server would wipe it clean.

Comment: Where should I put this?  Does this go into my Controller?

Comment: It's giving me this error `You must set Plaid::Client.client_id before using any methods which require authentication! It's current value is.. E.g. add a Plaid.config do .. end block somewhere in the initialization code of your program.):`

Comment: I'd try moving the top half of the code (the part before user=) to an initializer

Comment: just to be sure, can you try adding some logging to the initializer and making sure its running?

Comment: It works with the Plaid Ruby Gem.  Thank you for teaching me a lesson.

Comment: my initial guess would be the gem isn't in the gemfile.lock but you can also look at the heroku logs and find a stacktrace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118063/discussion-between-jgrant-and-matthew-arkin).

Answer (score 0):

Just create new method for plaid, smth like below.

Also, Good to use HTTP client or REST client

[HTTP client](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient)

[REST client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

```
def create
    res = plain_curl(params)
    puts res.inspect #there you will see your respond json obj in rails console.
end

private

def plain_curl(params)
  #it should return you json object, if not just add return before result.
  results = `curl https://tartan.plaid.com/exchange_token \
    -d client_id="CLIENT_ID" \
    -d secret="SECRET_KEY" \
    -d public_token="#{params[:public_token]}" \
    -d account_id="#{params[:meta][:account_id]}"`
end
```

Comment: I was able to get this running with something similar to what you have.

Comment: Piping to shell especially when it involves user input is a major security flaw, this is a horrible answer!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MatthewArkin How else would one connect to an API with some security with figaro, .yml file in rails?

Comment: Ruby has a built in HTTP client http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html or RestClient is a popular gem, or you can use Plaid's Ruby gem.

Comment: @MatthewArkin Yes, i could mention about http client, i just used my phone to answer this question. http client is another solution. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient

Comment: Could or should? This answer should definitely have a disclaimer about piping user input to the shell. Without proper sanitization of params this is definitely vulnerable to an attack, and since this post is about Plaid, that attack could leave bank account numbers and routing numbers vulnerable

Comment: Thank you for the information!  The Plaid Ruby Gem and HTTP client is helpful.  Nevertheless, I reached out to Plaid about piping to cURL.  Here's their response "As long as the requests are not exposed on the client side, meaning that the client Id and secret are not exposed – you should be fine to use a request handler and make calls directly to the API."  My Client ID and Secret Key are not exposed... I am using Figaro and have the ids stored in my application.yml file.